# Crear base de datos y tablas desde java

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, postgresql

Estoy desarrollando un SaaS y estoy en la parte de base de datos, lo que quiero hacer es crear una base de datos en postgresql por cada cliente que se registre pero no se como crearlas desde java puesto que el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
CREATE DATABASE "Inventarios"
WITH OWNER = postgres
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
LC_COLLATE = 'Spanish_Mexico.1252'
LC_CTYPE = 'Spanish_Mexico.1252'
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Sin embargo no estoy seguro si de esa manera debo trabajar porque no puedo ejecutarlo debido a que en la cadena de conexión me pide el nombre de la base de datos y eso es lo que aun no se crea, también encontré información referente a crearla mediante archivos .bat en windows pero no se como hacerlo en linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A no ser que uses un framework para bases de datos como Hibernate vas a tener que abrir la conexión (con el nombre que pongas como parámetros) y lanzar el código SQL para crear tablas manualmente. 
Ejemplo:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(user_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,username varchar(225) NOT NULL UNIQUE,password varchar(225),islogged varchar(10))");
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

*El parámetro String[] args del método main contiene los parámetros pasados desde el sistema operativo, vas a tener pasárselos desde tu bat o sh a tu java compilado .class

*Para conectarte a la base de datos y crearla desde Java debes conectarte a la base de datos de mantenimiento que no se puede borrar y lanzar el comando.

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
```

Comment: Pero lo que quiero hacer en especifico es crear la base de datos desde java y luego las tablas

Comment: Madre de Dios gracias jajaja lo probe y funciono a la primera,

Comment: Esa base de datos de mantenimiento también se crea automáticamente si instalo postgresql en linux?

Comment: Siempre se crea, un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, me estaba complicando la vida con lo que iba encontrando en internet

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la mejor forma de crear base de datos...
no se necesita usar la bd del sistema.

String drive = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

```
    try {
        cnx = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(drive,user,paswd);
        ps = cnx.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE "+bd);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

este código los uso en mi sistema y siempre ha funcionado.